# nosetests not finding test in subdirectory

Tags: python, nose

I have the following structure for my package

```
Project
- __init__.py
- my_mod
-- test
-- __init__.py
-- test_my_mod.py
```

If I run the nosetests in the project folder it doesn't find my tests, but if I run in the test folder then it picks it up.

Any ideas what could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `__init__.py` file in your Project directory. It doesn't look like you intend for Project to be a Python package, so you don't need it. Then, having this directory structure:

```
Project
└── my_mod
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── some_module.py
    ├── test
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── test_my_mod_again.py
    │   └── test_my_mod_yet_again.py
    └── test_my_mod.py
```

Running `nosetests` inside Project will now run your tests, both inside the my_mod/ directory and inside the test/ directory.

Of course, the contents of the test files should contain something that `nosetests` can recognize as a test, such as:

```
import unittest
from my_mod import some_module

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_the_number(self):
        assert some_module.double(10) == 20
```